# Как передать значение переменной из JS в php через hidden-переменную

Tags: javascript, php, html

Я конечно понимаю, что это старый и много раз обсужденный вопрос, но я никак не могу понять, как это работает. Потратил уже больше месяца...
Буду очень признателен, если сможете понятно объяснить с примером, как это сделать имено через hidden-переменную, повесив событие на нажатие кнопки  на форме OnClick. Я, к сожалению, даже не до конца понимаю принцип, как передать. Как забрать потом из $_POST мне понятно.

Comment: `value` любого `input[type="hidden"]` внутри формы будет передано на сервер после субмита. В целом, тут даже js не нужен - только форма с атрибутами `action` и `method` и с кнопкой.

Comment: Как было неоднократно сказано, отправка значения скрытого поля НИЧЕМ не отличается от отправки полей других типов. То есть ЛЮБОЙ пример отправки формы аяксом будет работать и для скрытых полей тоже.

Answer (score 0):

Изучите формы. Тип hidden у поля делает поле скрытым на форме, и больше ничем не отличается от других полей. Отправляется форма по нажатию инпута с типом submit, то есть события onclick не нужно. Если хотите отправку формы без перезагрузки страницы, или отправку значения какой то переменной без перезагрузки страницы то это другой вопрос, никак не связанный с полем на форме типа hidden. Если вы хотите отправить значение переменной в таком поле вместе в формой, то просто измените значение этого поля.

```
var varToSend = "Содержимое переменной для отправки";

$('[name="hidden-field"]').val(varToSend);
// для такого поля:
// <input type="hidden" name="hidden-field">
```